# Meteor, it hangs at “Starting your app” not only under the Windows, but also under Linux

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb, meteor

I'm just trying to feel Meteor.
I have a Meteor 1.4 project I tried to run in on Windows 7.

After it hangs at “Starting your app” I found the recommendations of the Stack and I tried to meet them.
Like I did:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample
```

but it does not solve the problem.

Then I thought that the problem is Windows and went on **c9.io**  there is in fact set to Linux.

At first it was not bad and I saw:

**--> Started proxy**
**--> Started MongoDb**
**...**

But there was a small problem - that the default meteor start your server on localhost: 3000 and do not like it c9.io.

Of course, I followed the advice and started meteor with set the ip and port:
**meteor --port $IP:$PORT**

What was my surprise when I saw a familiar picture:

**--> Started proxy**
**Starting your app...**

and it hangs ...

What to do?  Can set locally Linux ? However, after the experiment with c9.io I am not very sure that it will work.

Comment: Run meteor npn install, then simply run meteor.
Please wait for some time until package dependencies get installed. This should be work.

Comment: I took your advice and run   meteor npn install  in project directory. Then launched a meteor but saw nothing new.  All the same: --> Started proxy
Starting your app...  and it hands.

Comment: You can try with some other project. That can help you to find the real issue. If app run then there is some issue in code else there is some issue with meteor in your system.

Comment: I created a project with a different name, and did the same actions.   The result remains the same.    Then I locally installed Linux on a second machine.  It all worked fine. Under Win7 the problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem on Chromebook through Cloud9 trying to test Meteor's React showcase app using the suggested command `meteor create ~/simple-todos`.

If it can be of any help, I overcame the issue by creating the app higher up using command `meteor create simple-todos` followed by `cd simple-todos` and `meteor --port $IP:$PORT`.

Now works like a charm!

Comment: I was surprised that you have everything worked out.
Before that, I did the same thing - but the result was negative.
I decided to look again at C9.
I clean out there all the contents of the working folder and reinstall all.
Launched Meteor and .... "miracle" - and it works. 

Apparently the problem was an extra folder with node modules in the root directory.

Comment: You can narrow your sollution to this: meteor --port $IP:$PORT - it works well. On local machine (not Cloud9) you need to specify env variables $IP and $PORT or write them manually in meteor run command

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to install newest node version. I am not sure that will help but I saw other posts, that says this will solve the problem.

Comment: I and so it is a fresh version of Node, but it looks like Meteor tightens their own addiction.
   I've spent a lot of time picking Win 7 and I do not want any more.
I just installed Linux on a second machine.
Launched there Samba and Open SSH  and this is my problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this issue. There are 3 ways for this atm:

1. meteor reset - it lets you run your app but you lose all db data
2. set/export MONGO_URL="mongodb://login:password@someserver:27017/databasename/" - if you point some mongodb different than meteor mongo local db it seems to work also
3. The best one (IMO): run with different port, for example I run it with command: meteor --port 3002. If I do it this way there is never problem with starting your app hanging

I think it is some mongo - meteor related issue, I believe meteor devs will solve it sooner or later.

If you need to keep it on 3000 port try 1-2 sollutions or make some proxy (for example with nginx like here: [nginx how to proxy](https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-proxy-port-80-to-2368-for-ghost-with-nginx/)